# How to create igraph mult-graph list

Tags: r, igraph

I have a number of networks, currently represented as edgelists, and I can create individual igraph objects from them:

```
> nodes <- read.csv("nodes.csv",header=T,as.is=T)
> links <- read.csv("edges.csv",header=T,as.is=T)
> net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=T)
> net
IGRAPH f40255d DNW- 255 458 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), word (v/c), type (e/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges from f40255d (vertex names):
 [1] s001->s002 s001->s004 s001->s006 s001->s013 s001->s018 s001->s020
 [7] s001->s025 s001->s027 s001->s031 s001->s032 s001->s033 s001->s034
[13] s001->s035 s001->s037 s001->s038 s001->s041 s001->s042 s001->s044
[19] s001->s046 s001->s047 s001->s050 s001->s051 s001->s052 s001->s055
[25] s001->s059 s001->s060 s001->s064 s001->s065 s001->s067 s001->s068
[31] s001->s069 s001->s070 s001->s072 s001->s074 s001->s075 s001->s078
[37] s001->s081 s001->s088 s001->s091 s001->s092 s001->s093 s001->s098
[43] s001->s100 s001->s103 s001->s111 s001->s112 s001->s112 s001->s118
+ ... omitted several edges
```

But I want to analyze I want to analyze these using the graphkernels package in R, which requires a list of igraph graphs.  I have looked over the docs but I can't find any guidance on how to turn a number of these into a list. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Sorry if this is a dumb question.  I am minimally proficient in R.

Update: I tried creating 3 igraph objects and putting them in a list with

```
g <- list(net1,net2,net3)
```

But when I try to run this I get

```
> result <- CalculateWLKernel(g,5)
Error in CalculateKernelCpp(graph.info.list, par, 11) : 
  vector::_M_default_append
In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

So obviously something isn't right.

Comment: that's actually how you're supposed to make a list of graphs. I think the issue might be within one of your graphs. The below worked for me:  `g1 <- graph_from_atlas(sample(0:1252, 1));
g2 <- graph_from_atlas(sample(0:1252, 1));
g3 <- graph_from_atlas(sample(0:1252, 1));

g_list <- list(g1, g2, g3);

CalculateWLKernel(g_list, 11);`

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea how to debug the graph? The error message isn't very informative.

Comment: What do the warnings say?  I would start with a list of smaller graphs. Also, I would check to see if all graphs are of a similar type: i.e. All are either named or unnamed, all have the same vertex and edge attributes, and if all of those attributes are of a similar type (character, numeric, boolean)